# Overriding func in Swift

Tags: swift, functional-programming

I am learning Swift and I am following a tutorial from Paul Hegarty on how to build a calculator using Polish Inverse Notation. The code looks like this:

```
@IBAction func operate(sender: UIButton) {
    let operation = sender.currentTitle!
    if userIsEnteringData{
        enter()
    }
    switch operation {
    case "×": performOperation {$0 * $1}
    case "÷": performOperation {$1 / $0}
    case "+": performOperation {$0 + $1}
    case "−": performOperation {$1 - $0}
    case "√": performOperation {sqrt($0)}
    case "sin": performOperation {sin($0)}
    case "cos": performOperation {cos($0)}
    case "π": performOperation{$0 * M_PI}
    default: break
    }

}

func performOperation (operation : ( Double, Double ) -> Double){

    if operandStack.count >= 2 {
        displayValue = operation(operandStack.removeLast(), operandStack.removeLast())
        enter()

    }
}

func performOperation (operation : Double -> Double){

    if operandStack.count >= 1 {
        displayValue = operation(operandStack.removeLast())
        enter()

    }
}
```

The xCode compiler does not like the second instance of the performOperation function and reports that it has already been defined previously. The error it reports is:

`Method 'performOperation' with Objective-C selector 'performOperation:' conflicts with previous declaration with the same Objective-C selector`

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Is your class subclassing NSObject?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29670644/309046

Comment: @flashadvanced the class definition is as follows: 

class ViewController: UIViewController {
....
}

I guess that UIViewerController inherits from UIResponder : NSObject

Answer (score 5):

I am not aware of your class declaration but the most possible issue in this case is that you inherit from an `@objc` class. Objective-C does not support method overloading but Swift does. So either you shouldn't be inheriting from am `@objc` class if you can or you can just use different method names.

For reference you can read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29457720/swift-compiler-error-which-i-dont-understand)

Comment: Thank you for the pointing me to the reference. After reading the post I better understand the issue and possible fix. The route of the problem is that my class sort of breaks the MVC pattern as I have mixed "view" and "model". By splitting the "model" code into a separate class which does not inherit from UIControl I should be able to have two versions of the performOperation function one ( Double, Double) -> Double and a Double -> Double.

Comment: If my post answered your question you can accept it by clicking the tick.