# Overloaded functions in swift error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am new to swift and have an error in the following code. I have one function with two different parameters. Xcode(version 6) is giving an error on the second definition with a parameter as a function which takes one value.Here is the code:

```
func performOperation(operation: (Double, Double) -> Double) {
    if(operandStack.count >= 2){
        displayValue = operation(operandStack.removeLast(), operandStack.removeLast())
        enter()
    }
}

func performOperation(operation: Double -> Double){
    if(operandStack.count >= 1){
        displayValue = operation(operandStack.removeLast())
        enter()
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show the error that you're having...

Comment: show the error because this overload is legal and nothing wrong with it

Comment: method performOperation with objective-C selector 'performOperator:' conflicts with previous declaration

Comment: i have two calls to the function performOperation -

Comment: performOperation{ $1 - $0 }
performOperation{ sqrt($0) }

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
Another solution is add `private` before method definition ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29457720/compiler-error-method-with-objective-c-selector-conflicts-with-previous-declara/29670644#29670644)):

```
private func performOperation(operation: (Double, Double) -> Double) {
    if(operandStack.count >= 2){
        displayValue = operation(operandStack.removeLast(), operandStack.removeLast())
        enter()
    }
}

private func performOperation(operation: Double -> Double){
    if(operandStack.count >= 1){
        displayValue = operation(operandStack.removeLast())
        enter()
    }

}
```

**Original Answer:**
Looks like your methods are defined in class that is inherited from some Objective-C class, for example:

```
class TestClass : NSObject {  
    func test(a : String) {}
    func test(a : UInt) {}
}
```

Compiler will produce such error:

> Method 'test' with Objective-C selector 'test:' conflicts with
>   previous declaration with the same Objective-C selector.

To fix that you need avoid inheritance from Objective-C class:

```
class TestClass {  
    func test(a : String) {}
    func test(a : UInt) {}
}
```

This variant will work correct.

The problem is that Objective-C doesn't support methods overloading, but Swift does. That's why you need create pure Swift class.

Comment: This function is defined in class ViewController: UIViewController

Comment: @sanjivsoni UIViewController is ObjC class. Consider create separate Swift class and define these functions there. Then you will be able to use that class in ViewController: UIViewController class.

Comment: @sanjivsoni See my update in answer.