# Method 'fontWithName(_:size:)' conflict with Objective-C selector

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uifont

I am trying to create an extension for `UIFont`. But that show error describe below

> Method 'fontWithName(_:size:)' with Objective-C selector
>   'fontWithName:size:' conflicts with previous declaration with the same
>   Objective-C selector

Extension class code:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

extension UIFont {

    class func fontWithName(fontName: String, size fontSize: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
        return UIFont(name: fontName, size: fontSize + 5)!
    }
}
```

See Image [image: *enter image description here*]

Comment: So basically you just want to make all the app fonts 5pt bigger.

Answer (score 1):

This method name is not agreed because, there is already an `init` method present in `UIFont` class.

```
// Returns a font using CSS name matching semantics.
    public /*not inherited*/ init?(name fontName: String, size fontSize: CGFloat)
```

Now, Swift parses your method and finds it similar to default `init` method in `UIFont`.

```
// Returns a font using CSS name matching semantics.
+ (nullable UIFont *)fontWithName:(NSString *)fontName size:(CGFloat)fontSize;
```

Try changing your method name without losing its purpose (name telling purpose.) You'll get your method working.

Example:

```
func fontName(fontName: String, size fontSize: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
    return UIFont(name: fontName, size: fontSize + 5)!
}
```

Comment: then i need to use this custom method for set font right?

Comment: Yes, you'll use this method.

Comment: how to call this method?

Comment: And does this method effect font which are set from storyboard?

Comment: No. It will not reflect changes in Storyboard. It works only when you explicitly set the font property. Ex: label.font = yourMethodReturnedFont

Comment: ok thanks for answer but i need class which affect the storyboard changes as well. +1 for ans

Answer (score 0):

Objective C does not support method overloading and since NSFont is a Objective C class which already has a method with that name it results in a conflict. However if you still want to use that name for the method you could check out this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31500740/1949494 .Otherwise just rename the method.