# Swift Overloading issue

Tags: ios, swift, overloading

As we know, the `Swift` language allows Function Overloading, in `Objective-c` the overloading is not legal.

So I test in my demo project:

```
import UIKit

class FuncOverLoad: NSObject {

func helloFuc (_ what:String) {

}
func helloFuc (_ what:Int) {

}


func helloFuc() -> String {

    return "one"

}
func helloFuc() -> Int {

    return 1

}
}
```

But, why there comes the error:

> Method ‘helloFuc’ with Objective-C selector ‘helloFunc:’ conflicts with previous declaration with the same Objective-C selector

I take the picture:

[image]

Why comes the issue, if `Swift` function overloading is legal?

Comment: That's a bad duplicate for this question. A much better one would be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29457720/compiler-error-method-with-objective-c-selector-conflicts-with-previous-declara?s=1|6.5289

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, removing `: NSObject` would clear the errors.

Comment: if subclass of `NSObject`, if is related to `Objective-C` ?

Comment: if this, the Swift's Overloading characteristic is little actual significance in development iOS, because the `vc`, or `controls` and so on.

Comment: Subclassing `NSObject` implies `@objc`, so you're bound by the same rules as Objective C