# Same Objective c selector

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

My project was running normally. After I ran a pod install to add another project, I got this error. "Method `tabBar(_:shouldHijack:)` with objective-c selector `tabBar:ShouldHijack:` conflicts with method `tabBar(_:shouldHijack:)` with objective-c selector. This happens when I remove override from the function, here is the line of code.

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, shouldHijack item: UITabBarItem) -> Bool {

}
```

Comment: Chek this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29457720/compiler-error-method-with-objective-c-selector-conflicts-with-previous-declara

Comment: Check if the method name is correct. Normally, for any delegate methods, you shouldn't have the `override` keyword